# How to make Wordpress save_post_($post-type) hook works with multiple Custom Post Types

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-hook

I have an issue related save_post_($post-type) hook and ACF gallery field.

I got this code snippet from somewhere. Let me explain: I created an ACF gallery field (`acf-gallery` is the field name) shown in Custom Post Type (`cpt1` is the slug) then use this snippet to set the first image of this gallery as the featured image when saving just like what Woocommerce do.

But what if I want it to work with another Custom Post Type (let's say the slug is `cpt2`)? Can I use `array( 'cpt1', 'cpt2' )` to replace `cpt1`? Is there a way to include multiple custom post types?

```php
/* Set the first image generated by ACF gallery field as featured image */

add_action( 'save_post_cpt1', 'set_featured_image_from_gallery' );

function set_featured_image_from_gallery() {

    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;

    $images = get_field('acf_gallery', $post_id, false);
    $image_id = $images[0];

    if ( $image_id ) {
        set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $image_id );
    }
}
```

I edited this snippet using save-post hook according to comments below. But I don't know if it's valid. Can someone help?

```php
/* Set the first image generated by ACF gallery field as featured image */

add_action( 'save_post', 'set_featured_image_from_gallery' );

function set_featured_image_from_gallery($post_id) {

    if (get_post_type($post_id) != array( 'cpt1', 'cpt2')) {
        return;
    }

    $has_thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id);

      if ( !$has_thumbnail ) {

        $images = get_field('acf_gallery', $post_id, false);
        $image_id = $images[0];

        if ( $image_id ) {
          set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $image_id );
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: The general `save_post` hook should fire for _all_ post types (incl. pages), so you could use that, you'll just need to check the actual post type inside your callback function first then, so that you don't accidentally apply the update to other types than you intended.

Comment: And there really is no need to work with the global post id in this place (I would not be too sure, if that always points to the correct post - if this hook fires during a batch update or something, there might be potential for things to go wrong) - the hooks can pass post id and post content directly to the callback function.

Comment: You can justs use the normal `save_post` and then check the type in the `$post`

Comment: @CBroe I just modified the code and remove global $post, can you check it out? I am just a WordPress noob.

Comment: @Stender Hi, could you please check the modified version? I have no idea if it is valid or makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use `save_post` hook, `$post_id` variable, `get_post_type` and `in_array` functions.

```php
function set_featured_image_from_gallery($post_id)
{
    $included_cpts = array('cpt1', 'cpt2', 'cpt3');

    if (in_array(get_post_type($post_id), $included_cpts)) {

        $has_thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id);

        if (!$has_thumbnail) {

            $images = get_field('acf_gallery', $post_id, false);

            $image_id = $images[0];

            if ($image_id) {

                set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $image_id);
                
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'set_featured_image_from_gallery');
```

Comment: This seems a better solution. But I have to remove $has_thumbnail otherwise the featured image won't be updated if I rearrange gallery images. I don't know if there is a way to compare the existing CPT thumbnail with the first gallery image.